# How to Load puttygen RSA keys using Cryptolib in C++?

Tags: c++, private-key, public-key

I have API's to load the Private and public keys, developed using Cryptolib.

```
    CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey
    CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey
```

When I try to load the RSA(Private and Public) keys generated by puttygen , load functions crashes. Is it possible load the keys generated by Puttygen, in Cryptolib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crypto++ uses the PCKS #8 Private Key Information Standard for private keys and the X.509 Public key standard format as specified in [their documentation](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#Private_Key_Format). Puttygen uses the PuTTY format. These are not easily converted using C++, but it is possible. It's a lot easier just to export to OpenSSH format from within puttygen though.

If you still want to do it programmatically, you can use the [Chilkat CKSshKey library](https://www.example-code.com/vcpp/ssh_ppk_to_pem.asp) which was developed for just this purpose. You can see an example of converting a PuTTY private key to OpenSSH PEM (which is what Crypto++ will read) [here](https://www.example-code.com/vcpp/ssh_ppk_to_pem.asp).

Comment: I tried the above suggested and could able to load the private key as specified in https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#Private_Key_Format
But getting BER decode error, when I try to load public key. Please check for more Description. Am I missing something ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129346/unable-to-load-putty-generated-public-key-using-crypt